# How to easily create a landing page for contents with specific tag

Tags: 7, views, chaos-tool-suite, distributions

I'm building an intranet portal for a non-profit organization I work in, and currently figuring out how to make it easier for my colleagues to build a landing page that displays all contents tagged with x. For example, if they create a landing page called Jobs, all contents tagged with jobs will be updated on the Jobs page.

Think of it similar to OpenAtrium where you could create a section, then upon creating a content you could choose which section it will get automatically posted to.

Currently this is doable by:

1) Users creating a tag (i.e 'jobs'), then creating a view to pull all contents tagged with jobs. But this means I will have to give them permission to taxonomy, views, and page manager. Plus, the steps and interface are too daunting.

2) Using Panopoly module, I can easily add a 'content list' pane that can choose between different content type. Unfortunately it doesn't have an option to filter by tags. Is there any way to include this?

[image: Adding content list using Panopoly]

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can still do this easily with view panes. They play very nicely together with panels.

First step is to create the vocabulary you want to use / filter on. Then create a view pane with this vocab as an (exposed) filter.  By exposing this filter when a user adds this view pane to a panel, that exposed filter becomes a pane configuration option.  You can even expose content type as a filter and the user can choose what content types and terms they want to filter on when they add the pane.